# Apache Traffic Server: rule based on cookie

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

I need a reverse proxy which makes server mapping according to some value in cookie.

For example, if there is a variable "key" and it is equal to 2 (key=2) then request must be redirected to server 100.100.100.100.

Can apache traffic server do that?

P.S. I wrote this message to users mailing list of apache server traffic and this is the answer I get:

> This is an automatically generated message.
>
> danielxu@yahoo-inc.com is no longer with Yahoo! Inc.
>
> Your message will not be forwarded.
>
> If you have a sales inquiry, please email yahoosales@yahoo-inc.com and
>   someone will follow up with you shortly.
>
> If you require assistance with a legal matter, please send a message
>   to legal-notices@yahoo-inc.com
>
> Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the header rewrite plugin. In remap.config you'd have a rule like:

```
map http://example.com http://origin.example.com @plugin=header_rewrite.so @pparam=hdrs.config
```

and in hdrs.config I think this would work

```
cond %{COOKIE:key} ="2"
  set-destination HOST 100.100.100.100
```